# How can I "fake" a Mono Bold Libertine?

Tags: bold, typewriter, libertine

I would like to typeset some listings in Libertine/Libertinus Mono, but I've set the listings package to typeset the (octave/spice) language keywords in boldface, and these fonts (otherwise excellent, by the way) lack a Mono Bold face.

My question is: Is there any way to "fake" a bold version of Libertine/Libertinus Mono? I am thinking, for instance, on picking the Regular Bold types and printing them equally spaced, but perhaps this is too crude and won't work. Also, I don't know how to do that.

If it's too difficult, no problem: I can use DejaVu Mono or other monospaced font. I was being curious, simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}[
  BoldFont={Libertinus Mono},
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]

\begin{document}

Main: Test \textbf{test}

Sans: {\sffamily Test \textbf{test}}

Mono: {\ttfamily Test \textbf{test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really the two answers proposed suit me, but I voted for this one because it showed me that it's possible to "fake" a bold font, which is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use libertineMono.sty. It provides a bold monospaced variant.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that the libertine package includes a bold monospaced. The fact is that, being a non-expert tex user, I tended to use \fontspec and \setmainfont when compiling with XeLaTeX, because I thought (erroneously) that those font packages are solely for pdfTeX. I still have doubts on which font packages can I use with XeLaTeX, but this is perhaps another question.